# haystack search startswith

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Why when i use:

```
users = SearchQuerySet().all()
users = users.filter(name__startswith='foo')
```

i have query with result. And when i use

```
users = SearchQuerySet().models(UserProfile)
users = users.filter(name__startswith='foo')
```

i have empty query

Thx :)

Comment: What models are being returned by your first query?

Answer (score 0):

From all your models, in which one did you create a `SearchIndex`?  Do you have a `SearchIndex` for `UserProfile`, something like:

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack import site


class UserProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    ...

site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileIndex)
```

You can only see models that you have indexed.  From the code you've posted, it looks like you haven't indexed `UserProfile` but some other models.